# Pyttsx3 Account for punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx3

I was wondering if it was possible to detect how long a period takes in pyttsx3, I'm trying to build a live subtitler, that gets the script and then basically provides the amount of time each word lasts for. (english isnt first language, so script might not have right logic.)

```
    def count_syllables(self, word: str):
        vowels = "aeiouy"
        count = 0
        prev_char_was_vowel = False

        for char in word.lower():
            if char in vowels:
                if not prev_char_was_vowel:
                    count += 1
                prev_char_was_vowel = True
            else:
                prev_char_was_vowel = False

        if len(word) == 1:
            count = 1

        return count
```

also new to stackoverflow, so sorry if there are any errors.

Comment: what is the actual question ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how long a period takes when pyttsx3 uses tts to say it (a letter might take x amount of seconds, but I don't know how long punctuation would take)

Comment: okay,  how does this relate to the code since it is not called anywhere in the example ?!?